# IntelliSense for LESS functions in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, less

Does anyone know of an extension that adds IntelliSense for LESS functions, like `ceil()`, `darken()`, etc.? Web Essentials 2015.3 adds enhanced CSS support and Web Compiler adds LESS compilation, but as for LESS function IntelliSense, I haven't been able to find anything.